# Not showing decimal values when substarcting decimal numbers in MS Access query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

if my ".SubItems(2).Text" is 12.5 and "[quantity]" is 15 , then it is storing '3' instead of 2.5' , the data type of the quantity column is number with decimal format..
pls help me on this...

```
"update purchase set [quantity] = [quantity] - " & CDec(.SubItems(2).Text) & " where (ID =  " & .SubItems(7).Text & ")"
```

Comment: How many decimal places did you set for this column?

Comment: its default precision 18

Comment: Precision is something else. Look here http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/set-the-number-of-decimal-places-to-display-in-a-field-or-control-mdb-HP005188847.aspx

Comment: i set the decimal place to 2, but in access also when i try to change the whole number to something like 3.4 or 3.2 it automatically roundup to 3..

Comment: Did you save the table designer? Maybe your table data window was opened before the change?

Comment: ya i saved it , bt no success

Comment: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=777545

Comment: solved the problem, it was the problem with Microsoft product as per this article and they gave the solution. . .
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920359

Comment: Thanks for your help Amiram Korach

Comment: Hi Jexfer, you might like to post that as an answer to your question. Just include a few words from the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around this problem, manually set the Field Size property of the column(quantity in my case) to Double or to Decimal.

Click the DataSheet tab. In the Views group, click the arrow under View, and then click Design View.

Note If the table has not already been saved, you will be prompted to save the table with a table name that you provide.
Locate the column that you want to change, and then set the Field Size property of the column to Double or to Decimal.

Note If you set the Field Size property of the column to Decimal, you must also set the Scale property of the column. When you set the Scale property, you specify the maximum number of digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal separator.
    Save the table.

For more details, see:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920359